# Should atomic groups be used all the time to speed up failure?

Tags: regex, perl, optimization

As a common example, say we want to match some word pattern `$word_pattern` but there may be whitespace surrounding it.  This is very common usage of regex.  Normally people will write

```
/\s*$word_pattern\s*/
```

But that is inefficient in case of failure isn't it?  Shouldn't the efficient code be:

```
/(?>\s*)$word_pattern\s*/
```

But I never see that actually written...

Addition:  yes I did now benchmark it, and since one of the responders may have issues with whitespace here, I don't want to use it.

So now I have a very long file `a.txt` (1GB) filled entirely with character `a`.

And then

```
perl -ne 'print !/a*b/' < a.txt

perl -ne 'print !/(?>a*)b/' < a.txt
```

both take significant, but SAME, amount of time (over and above the time it takes to read in the file itself).

I don't understand that at all .  Can someone explain how can that be??  Perl documentation clearly says, that in the first case, there would be backtracking going on.

Comment: what do you mean under "case of failure"?

Comment: @IlyaBursov I presume that means if the string doesn't match.

Comment: really don't see any difference between variants, second is longer, harder to read and maybe will take a little bit more time to execute

Comment: @IlyaBursov, why do you reckon it is longer??  Let's say we have whitespace and we don't have a match. Then the engine will first gobble up all the whitespace, try to find a match, fail, then backtrack the last whitespace character, try to match the word again, fail, and so on, until the start of the whitespace, where it will finally end.  Seems like that is very inefficient?

Comment: Have you benchmarked this to see that the second regex is really faster?

Comment: @MarkGaleck second pattern 4 symbols longer then 1st. I cannot say for sure how different regexp parsers will behave, but I suppose in first case it will just find last white space before any other symbol, compare it and go further, without backtracking. if I'm wrong - then we need to check \s{0,1} too to compare real performance of at least 1 reg exp parser

Comment: *Always* using `(?>...)` would be cargo-culting. Many regexes are not backtracking-sensitive and wouldn't profit from such changes. Without knowing the exact effects of backtracking-modifying features, their usage is likely to do more harm than good. (Oh, and unless the exact matched substring is relevant (e.g. for `$&`), the `\s*` could be left out in your regexes without changing what they match)

Comment: In case anyone wasn't exactly sure what the `?>` does, like me, there is a good explanation at http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: Re "But I never see that actually written...", Even without optimization, most patterns can be written to fail quickly without `(?>...)`. The worse offender is using `.*?x` instead of `[^x]*x`.

Answer (score 1):

"Inefficient" no, but less efficient in case of failure **and** in case of success. You can see a real difference for a certain amount of data.

`(?>\s*)` or `\s*+` have two consequences:

1. The backtrack is forbidden in case of failure after in the pattern, (but the subpattern can be "backtracked" in one solid block)
2. backtrack positions inside an atomic group are not recorded by the regex engine, then the regex engine will work faster.

You can read this topic: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=664545 on the subject.

Comment: I apologize Casimir, but I do not understand your English.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: sorry, i will try to improve it!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I found out, is that, yes the second way should be faster, but because the first one is optimized in this simple case, it is as fast as the second one.

I should read the whole Camel book (but who ever does?).  Because, when I just read the canonical stuff, it implies `(?>...)` is faster.  And probably it is in complex cases.  But in simple cases, there is optimization, and Camel talks about that, it's just, I did not read it, because it was not needed to learn the language.

Thank you everybody.

Comment: Actually, not "complex" cases, just cases where you want the regex engine to backtrack. The original regular expression language (as implemented by `grep`) does not have backtracking. So a regexp (as opposed to regex) does not backtrack. Extended regular expression (as implemented by `egrep`) also does not have backtracking but it does have capturing which is a mild form of backtracking (the parser doesn't backtrack but needs to look up capture groups if you use `\1` etc.). It's only when you use look-aheads and look-behinds that backtracking is triggered.